# replace div id or class on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replace a div id/class when the screen width is at a certain size. So far this is what i have.

```
if ( $(window).width() < 750) {  
    $('#floating-control').attr('id','mobilecontrol');
}
```

Then i read using class rather than id is better. I change thing around so i have this

```
if ( $(window).width() < 750) {                     
    $('#floating-control').removeClass('floatcontrol').addClass('mobilecontrol');                
}
```

So far none of this worked. I am open to any  other suggestions. (jquery or javascript)

Comment: I see no reason why this should not work. Could you share a working demo please? Try creating one on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this);
      if (win.width() < 750) { 

      $('#floating-control').addClass('mobilecontrol');
      $('#floating-control').removeClass('floatcontrol');

      }
    else
    {
        $('#floating-control').removeClass('mobilecontrol');
      $('#floating-control').addClass('floatcontrol');
    }

});
```

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() < 514) {

    $('#floating-control').addClass('mobilecontrol');
    $('#floating-control').removeClass('floatcontrol');

  } else {
    $('#floating-control').removeClass('mobilecontrol');
    $('#floating-control').addClass('floatcontrol');
  }

});
```

```css
.floatcontrol {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.mobilecontrol {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floating-control" class="floatcontrol">I am text.</div>
```

Comment: Thank, this works, only problem is when I use developers tool to resize the screen, it does not work but it works when i manually drag the screen width. @fahad-hasan